# onmousemove = null doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, drag

I'm trying to find out how dragging works in native javascript. I made a simple javascript functions after researching it.

http://jsfiddle.net/FKM5S/1/

It works fine on all the browsers, except IEs!

The problem is that I can drag the element even after setting `document.onmousemove = null`

I can't even provide a step by step use case because it happens randomly.

I checked out other js samples on google and they have the same problem. One of them is http://ratfactor.com/misc/programming/simpledrag/test.html

Is this a known issue of IE or is there a workaround?

Comment: you could try `delete document.onmousemove`

Comment: @jbabey // it was throwing an error in IE

Answer (score 1):

Typically events are added using `document.addEventListener("mousemove", eventHandler)` and removed using `document.removeEventListener("mousemove", eventHandler)`.
The first parameter is the type of the event, the second the name of the handler.
Unfortunately there is no possibility of removing an anonymous handler function or a computed handler function as far as I know. So this will **not** work:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() { eventHandler(); });
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", function() { eventHandler(); });

document.addEventListener("mousemove", getEventHandlerFunc());
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", getEventHandlerFunc());
```

You have to provide exactly the same function-object in `document.removeEventListener`.

Comment: // removeEventListener is for modern browsers + iE9 as far as I know.

Comment: I see. Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=removeEventListener#Compatibility) reimplementation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.onmousemove = function(){return false;}`

Answer (score 0):

I had to set **onselectstart="return false;"** on the body tag for IEs. I think it's causing the problem. I still don't have a clue though..